# JQuery AjaxSetup BeforeSend Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I want to return a Promise from a `beforeSend` interceptor for jQuery. Basically I have a function registered as `beforeSend` which performs some asynchronous work. I want to defer the AJAX request from executing until my asynchronous work has completed. I know I can return `false` to cancel the AJAX request from `beforeSend`, but what about deferring it?

Comment: I don't think there's a good solution for this other than wrapping the $.ajax method in your own method.

Comment: Look into a custom transport

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are in trouble. BeforeSend for instance can return a boolean value so it loses the promisses benefits. One workaround is create an ajax request and create a new ajax request as a callback in done function. A cascade ajax request should solve your problem.

```
$.ajax({}).done(function() { $.ajax({}).done(function() {})})
```

Comment: This is pretty basic. Any recommendations for a more robust AJAX framework?

Comment: Can you share a sample?